# Asymptotes. Calculus.

Tags: calculus

I came across a question in a book asking for the asymptotes of $y=\sqrt{1+x^2}$. The answer says it as $2$, but I am pretty convinced that there is no asymptote. I somehow think the book is wrong. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: it's asymptotically linear as x goes to $\pm\infty$.

Comment: So there exists vertical asymtoes at +- infinty?

Comment: No, functions can't have vertical asymptotes at $\pm\infty$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right that it doesn't have vertical asymptotes anywhere, but it does have 2 oblique asymptotes. As $x\to+\infty$, 
$$
\sqrt{1+x^2}=x\cdot\sqrt{\frac1{x^2}+1},\text{ which approaches }\sqrt{0+1}=x,
$$
since for large $x$, $\frac1{x^2}\approx0$. This shows that the line $y=x$ is an oblique asymptote (since the function is getting closer and closer to $x$). When $x\to-\infty$, you can almost use the same argument, except you have to pull out a $-x$, so the line $y=-x$ is also an oblique asymptote.

Answer (score 0):

The book is correct, it has two oblique asymptotes. To show this, write $y= ax+b$, then:

$$a = \text{lim}_{x\to+\infty}\  \frac{f(x)}{x}\ \   and\ \   b = \text{lim}_{x\to+\infty}\  f(x) - ax$$

So taking the limit as $x \to +\infty$ we have

$a = \text{lim}_{x\to+\infty}\  \frac{\sqrt{1+x^2}}{x} = 1$ and $b = \text{lim}_{x\to+\infty}\  \sqrt{1+x^2} - x = 0$

So you have $y = x$ when $x \to \infty$.

Its up to you to find $y = -x$ when $x \to - \infty$.